# Android TV dongle soft-bricking with custom kiosk app installed

Tags: android, kiosk

We have an android kiosk app that runs on several dongles/boxes.
Some stick devices (mainly the MK808B Plus-without proper coolings) run fine for a while (1-2 weeks) and then bricks. (Sometimes we get a message "this machine has a serious error, need reboot")

We can't find the problem, so we just reinstall the rom, and the device will work fine again. when we test the device with CPU/GPU stability test there are no errors.

Our app is a fullscreen browser with some background threads, average CPU load 25-40% depending on content, running 24/7.

Questions:

1. What can kill a device that often, is this an android issue or a device issue?
2. Any other suggestions how can we debug our code (when it works fine on many other devices) to avoid these?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your kiosk app, especially if the app does not have root privileges.

The MK808B Android sticks don't seem to be of high quality, but they do have a low price tag! Considering that you are able to flash them to stock with no further issues makes it worthwhile.

Now, to answer "what could be causing these dongles to brick?" there are some areas to look:

1. **You mentioned that they don't have proper cooling.** Have you tried just taking a office fan and pointing it at the dongle while it's running during a two week period?
2. Are the dongles rooted? Take a look at the logs inside SuperSU app to see what could be wrecking the device.
3. SuperSU not present? The device ***may actually have*** su binaries installed but the lack of SuperSU would allow **any** app to modify the filesystem. Install SuperSU or Superuser/ChainsDD and see if it runs. No error messages = rooted
4. Is `/system` mounted RW? Hook the dongles up to ADB and run `mount -o ro,remount,ro /system` to lock the system files read-only. You may have to root your device. Try some one-click-root apps like Framaroot, Kingroot, Towelroot, etc. In this instance rooting will help us secure the device!
5. Does the device have bloatware? Delete any apps you don't need, this could solve the problem.
6. Does the kiosk browser allow downloads? A person could actually be trying to go after your entity, downloading malware on the dongles.

If none of these worked, try buying a better quality dongle.

Hope this helped